# access the output of get in then block

Tags: cypress

how to access the element that is yielded from .get().contains() in .then() function

My code is not entering the Then block. where am i doing wrong ?

```
cy.get(".c-header-listItem").contains("My Account").should(($link) => {
        expect(localStorage.read("CD-SessionId")).to.be.not.null;`enter code here`
    }).then(($link) => {
        $link.click();
    });
```

[image: Cypess UI]

I got the login from Cypress documentation https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Subjects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.should(elem => {})` behaves exactly as `.then(elem => {})`, except that the function passed to the `should` will retry until it doesn't throw any exceptions. With that in mind, the following code should work:

```js
cy.get(".c-header-listItem").contains("My Account").should(($link) => {
    expect(localStorage.read("CD-SessionId")).to.be.not.null;

    // Notice I have to wrap this to perform a Cypress 
    // click on it. $link is a native DOM object.
    cy.wrap($link).click();
});
```

---

This would also work, but the separation isn't necessary.

```js
cy.get(".c-header-listItem").contains("My Account").should(($link) => {
    expect(localStorage.read("CD-SessionId")).to.be.not.null;
});

cy.get(".c-header-listItem").contains("My Account").click();
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)